# Can a system like Stack Exchange work without active curation?

Tags: discussion

I think the idea of Stack Exchange was that knowledge would emerge from community input. However, someone has to have an idea in mind of what is desired, and constantly herd it in that direction, or it will wander. For example, Martin Fowler says this in his article [Is Design Dead](http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/designDead.html):

> In order to work, evolutionary design needs a force that drives it to
>   converge. This force can only come from people - somebody on the team
>   has to have the determination to ensure that the design quality stays
>   high.

So, if the goal has to exist at the beginning and be reinforced by active intervention, is it really an emerging construct? Can crowds be smarter than the person who is "in charge"?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "active curation"? For example, a site must have some way to remove spam... it must have users who work to remove bad content...

Comment: One article often mentioned in early posts about Stack Overflow is [A Group Is Its Own Worst Enemy](http://www.shirky.com/writings/herecomeseverybody/group_enemy.html). For example, here's Atwood's post mentioning it: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-group-is-its-own-worst-enemy/

Comment: Crowds are made up of people....

Comment: By "Active curation" do you mean "lots of users who actively work to curate the site" or "a small (perhaps just 1) person who inspires the community and directs the curation work they do" ?

Comment: Would this be better asked on [Community Building](http://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/)?  Ostensibly after being closed here, of course.

Comment: `3.) The third thing you need to accept: The core group has rights that trump individual rights in some situations. This pulls against the libertarian view that's quite common on the network, and it absolutely pulls against the one person/one vote notion. But you can see examples of how bad an idea voting is when citizenship is the same as ability to log in.` - from A Group is its own worst enemy.  I would also point out that Shirky is on the board of directors for Stack Exchange... or Overflow. Whatever that site is called. The second thing is important too, but well, read the entire thing.

Comment: Hmm, I guess if I got up to put my coat on and go home, everyone would leave. But, instead, I stay at the party... I was thinking in terms of a person with the vision of how this should go. If they are replaced by another, or by a group, usually the scenario falls apart. (RCA, anyone?) This is why we have an Executive in corporations and governments: one person holds a view of how things should be. A group cannot do this, because a group cannot have a single view. The word that grabs me is "converge". Rationality must converge on an answer, or it fails. If groups can't do this, 1 person must.

Comment: Isn't this why Area 51 exists? To get a critical mass of people who are already all pointed in the same general direction, before the site is allowed to exist? Yes, there's an issue with needing initial direction, but I don't see how this is relevant to SE, meta or otherwise.

Comment: Left to themselves, things go from bad to worse.

Answer (score 6):

I think the existence of several sites that dramatically changed direction ([Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/) spring immediately to mind) show that a site can thrive without a single person who is "in charge" and who curates the site.

The site's Meta functions like a board of directors to set policy, which the general crowd of diamonds and high rep users then implement. People come and go; the site persists.

Could the first few sites have achieved that? Probably not. We all bring our "norms" of SE sites with us, norms we learned from sites that had a stronger guiding hand. But at what point do we stop thinking of Jeff and Joel as being the ones guiding say, puzzling? I think that point is already reached.

Comment: Did the *Puzzling* site have a person who called for it and decided what it was about? Is that person still watching over it? If not, has the direction of the site changed? (RCA is still the best example that comes to mind.) Someone mentioned Area51 to start a site. But one person does that, a group doesn't all come in and click the mouse, like a ribbon-cutting ceremony.

Comment: presumably someone proposed it on area 51. But no single person watches over it and it transitioned from "questions about creating and solving puzzles" to "questions that are puzzles, answers are proposed solutions" mostly by hashing that out on the site meta over a substantial period of time.

Comment: So, "evolution" can be either directed by one person, or a group. I wonder what happens if the group can't converge on a particular decision? Also, I wonder how efficient it is to have a group making the decisions, versus one person? Or if the direction could change to an unfavorable one, or the group direction fall apart? (A single individual can leave or die also. Will, eventually... But a group could be 'immortal'.)